# Get buffer from post body in Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making an express application that handles post data. Because the request body could be any content type and/or binary, I would like `req.body` to be a `Buffer`. So what should I use to get a `Buffer` that represents the request body? Here is my code:

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // Get request body as buffer
  // Do something with the buffer
});
```

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.raw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

body-parser can help achieve this, code example would be as,

```
import express from 'express';
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const options = {
  type: 'application/octet-stream',
};
app.use(bodyParser.raw(options));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const bufferObject = req.body; // Get request body as buffer
  // Do something with the buffer
});
```

See more details about **Raw body parser** and default options needs to be supplied - [bodyParser.raw([options])](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions)